Advertising API - Resource not found
Good morning #linkedin,
I am trying to extract data from Advertising API campaigns that my company has on LinkedIn Ads. The issue we are facing is that when making the API request, we are unable to retrieve a list of campaigns and instead receive the error "Resource not found." Below you will find the code:
Obtain the access token with the necessary scopes
import urllib.parse

# Replace with your client_id and redirect_uri
scope = 'email openid profile r_ads'  # You can add more scopes if necessary, separated by a space
client_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
redirect_uri = 'https://www.XXXXX.es'
# Authorization URL parameters
params = {
    'response_type': 'code',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
    'scope': scope
}

# Build authorization URL
base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
authorization_url = f'{base_url}?{urllib.parse.urlencode(params)}'

print('Visit this URL in your browser to authorize the application:')
print(authorization_url)


import requests

def get_linkedin_campaigns(access_token, account_id):
    """
    Lista todas las campañas de una cuenta de LinkedIn Ads especificada.

    Parámetros:
    - access_token: str - Token de acceso OAuth2 para la API de LinkedIn.
    - account_id: str - Identificador de la cuenta de LinkedIn Ads.

    Devuelve:
    - dict: Un diccionario con los datos de las campañas o un mensaje de error.
    """
    url = f"https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2?q=search&account={account_id}"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0"  # Necesario para algunas APIs de LinkedIn
    }
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Esto lanzará una excepción para respuestas no exitosas
        return response.json()  # Devuelve el JSON con los datos de las campañas
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        return {"error": str(e), "details": response.text if response else "No response"}

# Uso de la función
access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'  # Reemplaza con tu token de acceso real
account_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'  # Reemplaza con tu ID de cuenta de LinkedIn Ads real
campaigns = get_linkedin_campaigns(access_token, account_id)
print(campaigns)

Here's a brief summary:

Action: Attempted to extract campaign data from LinkedIn Ads API.
Expectation: Expected to receive a list of campaigns.
Result: Received an error message "Resource not found."

